# splitting a string in python based on first occurrence of letter

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string

as an example, I have the string '10d45x'

I would like to take the string as an input and retrieve '10d' and '45x' separately.

some clarifications: the letters can always be of 1 character length but the numbers can be longer

I am trying to explore:

```
import re
re.split("[a-zA-Z]",'10d45x')
```

but unable to find the right parameters to get exactly what I want

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's not really clear what other patterns you might encounter. Do all the groups you want fit the pattern of some-numbers-and-a-letter? If so, it's just `re.findall(r'\d+\w', s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

#### option 1: (credits to Mark Meyer )

```py
import re
str = '10d45x'
print(re.findall(r'\d+\w', str))
```

#### option: 2

```py
str = '10d45x'
final_list = []
temp_list = []
for i in str:
    temp_list.append(i)
    if (i.isalpha()):
        final_list.append("".join(temp_list))
        temp_list = []
print(final_list)
```

```
>>> ['10d', '45x']
```

Comment: \w is too general, it also includes digits and the underscore character, use [A-Za-z]

Answer (score 0):

You can split directly looking back for a letter and forward for a digit:

```
>>> re.split(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)', '10d45x')
['10d', '45x']
```

Instead of splitting you can also capture:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\d+[a-zA=Z])', '10d45x')
['10d', '45x']
```